# How does Google's Website Optimizer do all its funky goodness with an unbalanced </noscript> tag?

Tags: google-website-optimizer

Last week one of the guy's at our office did a talk on [using Google's Website Optimizer for AB multivariate testing](http://youtu.be/pDQsfMZQ44A).  In the talk, he says that when you set it up you just add some special code to the page around the HTML you want to vary [ [see #3 under multivariate test here](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?answer=61149&cbid=12f2m8jp0akf0&src=cb&lev=%20index#m3) ]

```
<script>utmx_section("Headline")</script>
Welcome!
</noscript>
```

What's going on with that unbalanced tag at the end?  What magic is Google doing?

Comment: should be tagged `google-website-optimizer`, not `google-webmaster-tools`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `utmx_section("Headline")` command will execute as the document is parsed. If it emits a `<noscript>` tag using document.write() the browser will ignore that particular section, until it meets the `</noscript>` tag.

Here is the same trick, but with a h1:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Spike</title></head>
  <body>
    <script>document.write('<h1>');</script>
      Header
    </h1>
    <p>That's how...</p>
</html>
```

this will give a body looking like

```
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>That's how...</p>
```

Comment: Why they do it this way is beyond me though - if you want xhtml or have an XML oriented rendering engine the unbalanced </noscript> tag is a huge issue.

Comment: Ah, that's a better explanation than what Google has(http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=64418). +1